# File selector list not starting at the top

Tags: finder, attachments

When I go to attach a document in mail, I press the attach button, and the file selector dialog opens. However, the list starts 3 or 4 items from the top, so I have to scroll up a little to see the first few (and then back down to see the rest).

Any ideas what would cause this and how I would fix it?

Comment: What OS version do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any third party software installed that messes with the finder dialogs? Default Folder, Boomarang, etc.

When in doubt:

Quit all applications.
Cycle power on the computer.
Repair permissions and repair the disk.
Delete preferences for that application.